# How to connect two random people in a single thread using Laravel Broadcasting

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a **random real-time chat**, like Omegle.

I'm having trouble to connect two random people in a private thread using a wait list. What would be the best way to do it using **Laravel Broadcasting** and **Laravel Job**?

For example:

```
Route::get('/start', function () {
    // add me to the wait list
    // wait for another person
    // find another person
    // remove me and another person from the wait list

    // dispatch event
    App\Events\AnotherPersonFound::dispatch($anotherPerson, $threadId);
});
```

Comment: 'Trouble' how, in what way?

Comment: How to configure the **routes** and **events** to achieve a random chat?

Comment: So you want a full blown tutorial?

Comment: I'm going to flag this to be closed as being too broad because it does seem you're after a guide on how to create a real-time chat within Laravel - to which there are **plenty** of tutorials if you simply Google searched `"real time chat Laravel"`.  Here is such a guide : https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel/

Comment: I want to know how to join two random people that are waiting. I just edited my post, check it, please.

Comment: You do it via JS using Laravel Echo using `Echo.join()`. See the guide. You don't join people based on a route.

Comment: I agree with @AshleyBrown, there seems to be very little effort on your part. I have followed the exact tutorial that Ashley has posted and I have got it working, maybe start there before trying anything more complex, such as having a queue system

Comment: I'm not sure why you've put a bounty on this question. You don't add people into a 'chat' with a route if they're sitting on a page waiting, you do it with JS..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a channel and associate users with, after the event is dispatched.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting#presence-channels

You can also send a notification about a new match between people by using:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting#notifications